# ffmpeg Horizontal Y/C delay compensation from small format video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am working with some captured video from NTSC composite sources.

I found other threads about Y/C delay compensation , but they seem to involve more delay than I have and can not fully understand how to use it in my case. I have only a horizontal delay, far less than a vertical delay.

Here is an example

uncorrected
https://mediaarea.net/_/img/QCTools/image60.jpg

corrected
https://mediaarea.net/_/img/QCTools/image61.jpg

although my delay is more severe than the examples

Is there an easy way to correct this in ffmpeg or other?